# rails 4 validates presence and length on the same parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Is it a good idea to having validates like this:

```
validates :serialnumber, presence: true, length: {7..20}, format: {with: /\d{7,20/}
```

As you see it generates three errors if I don't type serialnumber.
I would like to see only one error.
If I type nothing, I would like to see 'serial number is required' only.
If I type `123ABC` I would like to see 'wrong length' only
And if I type `123-ABC-123` I would like to see 'wrong format' only

How to do it?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split it into 2 validators, check if this would work

```
validates :serialnumber, presence: true
validates :serialnumber, length: {7..20}, format: { with: /\d{7,20}/ }, allow_blank: true
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand then you want to see only one error message *at a time*. If that's the case then [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) method might help. For ex.

```
validate :serial_number_validation_one_by_one

private

def serial_number_validation_one_by_one
  if !self.serial_number.present?
    errors.add(:serial_number, "must be present!")
  elsif self.serial_number.length < 7 || self.serial_number.length > 20
    errors.add(:serial_number, "must have length between 7 and 20!")
  elsif self.serial_number.match(<your regex pattern here>)
    errors.add(:serial_number, "must be properly formatted!")
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that custom validation methods are called by `validate` not by `validates`.